# How can I insert specific date formats into a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some varchar(8) strings in a table that look like this.
20180630
20180331
20180630

If I select all, like this, they look fine.

```
Select Left(StartDate,4)+'-' + Substring(StartDate,5,2)+ '-'+Right(StartDate,2),
            Left(Expiry_Date,4)+'-' + Substring(Expiry_Date,5,2)+ '-'+Right(Expiry_Date,2)
From MyTable
```

The problem is that I am trying to insert records form one table into another, like this.

```
Insert Into TBL_TRANS_FINAL(CURRENCY,
                AMOUNT,
                Left(StartDate,4)+'-' + Substring(StartDate,5,2)+ '-'+Right(StartDate,2) as StartDate,
                EFFECTIVESTARTDATE,
                Left(Expiry_Date,4)+'-' + Substring(Expiry_Date,5,2)+ '-'+Right(Expiry_Date,2) as Expiry_Date)
    ...
select *
from TMP3 where IS_SPECIAL_DATE <> 'N' and  AsofDate <> ''  ;
```

I keep getting an error about: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Left'.`

This should be pretty simple, I think.  What am I missing here?

Comment: the error at AMOUNT, missing left bracket. ideally Insert into (column list) select columnlist from table where condition;

Comment: I have to ask, but why are not not storing dates as a `date`?

Comment: The absolute best approach would be to stop using strings to store dates. That is why we have the date datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `INSERT INTO tab(col_names) SELECT ... FROM ...` syntax:

```
Insert Into TBL_TRANS_FINAL(
    col_name1,
    --...
    col_name5
)
select 
   CURRENCY,
   AMOUNT,
   CAST(StartDate AS DATE),
   EFFECTIVESTARTDATE,
   CAST(Expiry_Date AS DATE)
from TMP3 
where IS_SPECIAL_DATE <> 'N' and  AsofDate <> '';
```

I would also store date as `DATE` type.

```
'YYYYMMDD' date literal:
Left(StartDate,4)+'-' + Substring(StartDate,5,2)+ '-'+Right(StartDate,2)
<=>
CAST(StartDate AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The form of the [`INSERT` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that you're trying to use here is:

```
INSERT [INTO] table_or_view_name ( column_list ) derived_table;
```

Your calls to the `LEFT` function fall within the `column_list` part of the statement, which is why you're getting a syntax error: the `column_list` is supposed to be nothing more than a list of names of columns in `table_or_view_name` whose contents will be filled by the output of the `derived_table` part of the statement (i.e., your `SELECT`). It is not valid to have string-manipulation going on in the `column_list`. Expressions of that sort should be in your `SELECT` instead.

Comment: Oh my!!  I can't believe I tried to do that formatting within the Insert statement and not the Select statement!!  Dumb!  It's just too hot in NYC to think straight right now...  thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the wrong syntax in your query. The correct syntax is `INSERT INTO table(col_names) SELECT value1, value2, func(value3)... FROM table`

Also, if the target column type is `DATE` then you may use SQL Convert function with appropriate style to convert source `VARCHAR` to target `DATE`. You may refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more styles.

```
Insert Into TBL_TRANS_FINAL
Select CURRENCY,
        AMOUNT, 
        convert(date, StartDate,112),       
        EFFECTIVESTARTDATE,
        convert(date, Expiry_Date,112)
```